# Strange "no such file to load -- redis-namespace" exception when start rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis

I'm using Rails 2.3.8 + redis + resque + redis-namespace

This is part of my `environment.rb`

```
  config.gem 'jrails'
  config.gem 'haml'
  config.gem 'redis'
  config.gem 'redis-namespace'
  config.gem 'resque
```

This is my `gem list`

```
redis (2.0.3)
redis-namespace (0.7.0)
resque (1.9.7)
```

When I start my server by 'script/server', it show such exception:

```
=> Rails 2.3.8 application starting on http://0.0.0.0:3000
no such file to load -- redis-namespace
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb:215:in `load'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/initializer.rb:307:in `load_gems'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/initializer.rb:307:in `each'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/initializer.rb:307:in `load_gems'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/initializer.rb:164:in `process'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `send'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `run'
/mnt/workspace/webtails/config/environment.rb:9
```

I have re-installed `redis-namespace` many times, and it always shows this error message. Where is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because this file doesn't exist. You need require 'redis/namespace'

```
config.gem 'redis-namespace', :lib => 'redis/namespace'
```